# Using json with jsondatetime

Tags: json, python-3.x

json.dumps gives an error if both json and jsondatetime are imported. The error is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):     
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>     
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 230, in dumps     
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
TypeError: encode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'o'
```

But I just import JSON, then json.dumps work fine. I don't know how to deal with this. I need jsondatetime as well

This works::

```
    import json
    json.dumps({'DbName': 'DB','Hostname': '10.0.0.6','DbUsername':'SYSTEM'})
    '{"Hostname": "10.0.0.6","DbName": "DB", "DbUsername": "SYSTEM"}'
```

This does not work::

```
    import jsondatetime
    import json
    json.dumps({'DbName': 'DB', 'Hostname': '10.0.0.6', 'DbUsername': 'SYSTEM'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 230, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
    TypeError: encode() missing 1 required positional argument: 'o'
```

Answer (score 0):

`jsondatetime` is a drop-in replacement for `json`. You should only have

```
import jsondatetime as json
```

From the [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/JSON-Datetime/):

> JSON-datetime is a very simple wrapper around Python simplejson loads method. It decodes datetime values contained in JSON strings.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Importing jsondatetime as json gives me a new kind of error               

>>> import jsondatetime as json
>>> json.dumps({"abc":"def", "hi":None})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/jsondatetime/jsondatetime.py", line 30, in dumps
    default=default, sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/json/__init__.py", line 237, in dumps
    **kw).encode(obj)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Comment: @SAziz I don't think it supports Python versions after 3.2.